# create new subkey in a registry using java

Tags: java, registry, addition

Can anyone tell me how can i create/add new sub key in a existing key of a registry and add DWord entry name with certain value using java?

For eg

I want to add HIMAL sub key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\JAVASOFT\PREFS. After that it will look like this HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\JAVASOFT\PREFS\HIMAL.And then add a new value.

THanks in advance

Comment: Have you even checked SO for writing into the windows library? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java?rq=1

Comment: in that example createkey function in not creating the sub key..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple java libraries that allow access to Windows registry. You can find them easily.

Additionally you can execute command line utility `reg` or use [code](http://alexradzin.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/access-windows-registry-with-pure-java.html) referenced from this [article](http://alexradzin.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/access-windows-registry-with-pure-java.html).